How to redirect requests for a URL which uses the default ports to a new URL which uses custom ports?
We have an .aspx web forms "web application" running IIS 10 and .Net Framework 4.8.
We want to move it from the "Default Web Site" to it's own site "MyApplicationSite".
The challenges are below.
We want the users to keep using the existing URL's that may be bookmarked.
The "Default Web Site" has the port number :80 and :443 bound.
When we create a new website, I believe it can not use ports :80 and :443 and must use  custom port numbers not already configured.
But the users must use the port numbers in the URL, correct? Given that the host/domain name is going to be the same.
Is there a way to redirect requests for the URL bound to the default port numbers to the new URL with custom port numbers, without the users needing to update their bookmarks?
If it is possible, what are the options to achieve this?

You can configure IIS as reverse proxy if you want to keep the old URLs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing Hire a consultant if you want step by step guidance.

whoever down voted, why? what's wrong

I believe it can not use ports :80 and :443 and must use custom port numbers not already configured. — that's either wrong belief or crap software. Decent web servers can host multiple HTTP sites on a single IP:port for more than 25 years, and HTTPS sites for more than 15 years.

You can have multiple websites binding to the same ports if you use different hostnames.
In example, you could bind one site to "somehost.somedomain.com" and the other one to "anotherhost.anotherdomain.com".
This assuming your users bookmarked the DNS name, not the IP address.
You mentioned port 443, so https is involved. You'll also need a certificate valid for both the hostnames you'll use.
